# Conf file for VHosts not working

Tags: linux, domain-name, virtual-host, httpd, drupal

Trying to set up a multi-site in drupal and use my.conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d to set the names of virtual hosts

PROBLEM I am having is getting a new domain name to direct to the drupal folder located in subdomain. It keeps pointing at root no matter how I change vhosts. Is there a trick I don't know about?

Comment: Please go here to see the answer to this question:

 http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74527/new-domain-url-for-multi-sites-linked-to-sub-domain-drupal-install/74664#74664

Comment: trivial - no sorry robot but this is link to actual answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this right? You have a domain with Drupal as a subdirectory (http://www.example.com/drupal, perhaps at /var/www/vhosts/example_com/drupal) and also want another domain to serve only that subfolder (http://drupal.greatdomain.com), but http://drupal.greatdomain.com is serving the same content as http://www.example.com.

Are you restarting Apache after changing my.conf?  Could you post that file (anonymize what you like), or at least DocumentRoot?

Comment: No, I have already got the subdomain to successfully run as a multi-site off the subdomain by adding virtualhost in my.conf.

Comment: I tried doing the same with a new domain name but it didn't work.

Comment: Yes restarting apache after but you see it only works in vhosts with subdomain running off subdomain not a new domain because then it will direct example.com/drupal.

Comment: with subdomain i just add VirtualDocumentRoot "var/www/html/drupal" to each subdomain running off main subdomain.

Comment: With subdomains the installer comes up in sub.example.com/install.php but with new domain name it comes only as example.com/drupal/install.php